# How to use mean value theorem For harmonic functions to prove this

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

The following question was asked in my complex analysis assignment and I am confused about how this should be done.

> Show that $\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln( \sin {\theta}) d{\theta} = -\pi \ln 2$ by applying the mean value theorem to $ \ln|1+z|$ for $|z|\leq r <1$ and then letting $r\to 1$.

If I use mean value theorem to $\ln(1+z)$,I get $ln|(1+z_0)| = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln|1+z_0+ r e^{i\theta}|d {\theta}$.

But how to change the $1+z_0 + re^{i \theta}$  in RHS into $\sin\theta$ if $r$ approaches $1$?

I am not able to manipulate into that.

Answer (score 1):

Set $z_0=0$, then
$$\begin{split}
0&=\frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\ln |1+re^{i\theta}|d\theta\\
&\rightarrow \frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\ln |1+e^{i\theta}|d\theta\\
&= \frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left |2\cos \frac \theta 2\right|d\theta\\
&= \ln 2 +\frac 1 {\pi} \int_0^{\pi}\ln |\cos \theta |d\theta\\
&= \ln 2 +\frac 1 {\pi} \int_0^{\pi}\ln (\sin \theta )d\theta\\
\end{split} $$

Comment: How did you changed$\rightarrow \frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\ln |1+e^{i\theta}|d\theta\\
$ to $= \frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left |2\cos \frac \theta 2\right|d\theta\\$? Can you please elaborate? I am geting $1+e^{i\theta} = 2 cos (\theta /2) \times( cos(\theta /2) + i sin(\theta /2) )$   . But unable to comprehend how did you wrote $1/2 \pi \int_{0^{2\pi}} ln | cos(\theta /2 + i sin(\theta /2)| d{\theta} $ =0?

Comment: Sure:$|1+e^{i\theta} |= 2| cos (\theta /2) | \times |cos(\theta /2) + i sin(\theta /2) | =  2| cos (\theta /2) | $

Comment: Can you please also tell how $ 1/\pi \int_{)}^{\pi} ln | cos (\theta) | d(\theta) =  1/\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} ln(sin\theta)  d(\theta) $?

Comment: $\int_0^\pi \ln |\cos\theta|d\theta=2\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \ln\cos(\theta) d\theta = 2\int_{\frac \pi 2}^0 \ln \cos(\frac \pi 2 -\theta)d(\frac \pi 2 - \theta) = 2\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \ln\sin(\theta) d\theta = \int_0^\pi \ln |\sin\theta|d\theta$